# Why am I unable to access LinkedList methods with List reference type object

Tags: java, list, collections

when I am creating object in this format `List obj = new LinkedList()` why am I unable to access `LinkedList` methods?

Comment: because `LinkedList` is hidden in supertype `List`.

Comment: If you need specific `LinkedList` methods, just use `LinkedList<T> obj = new LinkedList<>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

`List obj = new LinkedList()`

What you have is a `List`.  You've "stored" the `LinkedList` in it but you are treating it as a `List`.

On the other hand, with:-

`LinkedList obj = new LinkedList()`

You can treat it as a `LinkedList`

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about java.util.List it is an interface, while the LinkedList is a class, which implements the List.

[LikedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Thats why you can use only the interface methods.

Answer (score 0):

Cause compiler doesnt know what type of list you use, so with run-time type identification you can use only interface methods, and here, List is interface

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a variable of type List (an interface).

When other code references the obj variable, it can only assume that any object referred to using the obj variable implements the List interface.

To assert that the object referred to by obj is a Linked list, you would need to cast the obj to LinkedList, making a big assumption that the interface implementer is a Linked List.

While it is generally good to program with abstractions such as interfaces, if you need access to the methods provided by the raw type this indicates that you should use a reference to the raw type (in this case LinkedList) or use an interface other than List that supplies the method you need.

```
LinkedList<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();

public void expectsList(List<String> maybeLinkedList){

    maybeLinkedList.listInterfaceMethod(); // works ok

    LinkedList linkedList = (LinkedList<String>) maybeLinkedList; // CAST may fail if obj is not a linked list

    linkedList.linkedListMethod(); // If cast worked, this works
}

public void expectsLinkedList(LinkedList<String> aLinkedList){

    aList.listInterfaceMethod();  // Works because linked list honors the List interface

    List<String> list = aLinkedList; // also works because Linked list 'is a' kind of List

    list.listInterfaceMethod(); // works ok

    linkedList.linkedListMethod(); // We know the input object is a linked list

}
```

Note that that casting is just to illustrate the changing types - you do not need to cast to solve your problem in this case.